# Java Type Check in equals(): instanceof vs getClass()

Tags: java, equals

First, I am *not* asking for the difference between them.

I have an idea in mind and I would like more brain to verify, which seems able to take (most of) the pros of using both approach.

In brief, `equals()` in Java usually looks like this.

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (this and other is not of the same type) return false
    // then actual equals checking
}
```

The problem lies in the "*this and other is not of the same type*" checking.

One stream of people prefer using `if (! (other instanceof MyClass))`, which have the shortcoming of

- Easily lead to asymmetric result.  If other is a subclass of `MyClass` and has overridden `equals()`, `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(a)` will not be the same
- To avoid this, we need to avoid child class from overriding `equals()`, by declaring it final

The other stream of people prefer using `if (getClass() != other.getClass())`, which has the shortcoming of

- Violating Liskov substitution principle.  A child class of `MyClass` should be able to use in place of `MyClass`.
- Therefore `a.equals(b)` will be false if `a` is of `MyClass` while `b` is of a child class of `MyClass`, even the internal attributes are just the same.

---

I have an idea in mind I would want people to verify.

This approach should

1. If a child class overridden `equals()`, results should still be symmetric
2. A child class will still be able to be used as its parent type (in aspect of `equals()`, and `equals` is not overridden of course)

   ```
   public class Parent {
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object other) {
           if (other == null) return false;
           if (this == other) return true;
           if (!(other instanceof Parent)) return false;
           try {
               if (other.getClass().getMethod("equals", Object.class).getDeclaringClass() != Parent.class) {
                   return other.equals(this);
               }
           } catch(Exception neverHappen){}

           // do actual checking
       }
   }
   ```

The main idea is, if `this` encountered a `Parent` object, but that object's `equals()` is not declared in `Parent` (i.e. that object is a child class, with `equals()` overridden, I will delegate the `equals` invocation to the child class object (or may simply return false).

Is there any shortcoming of using this approach that I have overlooked? (I guess performance loss will be one concern, but I believe call of `getClass().method("equals").getDeclaringClass()` should be quite cheap?)

Comment: Not sure, but if the child class does `super.equals(..)`, you would get a stackoverflow. So you would end up rewriting the whole Parent class `equals(..)` in the child class, which is even worst design.

Comment: @Asoub ah.... exactly... I have only play around cases of parent vs child, parent vs overridden child, but forgot to try overridden child vs overridden child.  Turned out that if I want equals to be properly overridden, I will need separate methods to do it right :(

Comment: @Asoub reminded me something else: I always have an impression that using getClass() in type check of equals() will give me symmetric results for "extended equals" in child class, and the only drawback is suffering from violation of Liskov substitution principle. However a second though it is also suffering from the problem you mentioned, that super.equals() cannot be used, isn't it?

Comment: made an answer (to long for a comment). You could use `super.equals()` in a child, but then it could never be equal to a parent class.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, if the child class does `super.equals(..)`, you would get a stackoverflow. To prevent this, you would end up rewriting the whole parents `equals(..)` in each children, which is even worst design.

Somehow, it depends on how/why you implemented inheritance in the first place. Should a child be comparable to a parent ? Does the comparaison makes sense ? (edited)

If you override equals, then you're not respecting LSP, by definition.
If a child has more parameters (which means it overides the equals method), then it shouldn't be equal to its parent, and this is why we can compare using `getClass() != other.getClass()` in the parent. If you want to use the parent class's `equals()` in your child (so you don't have to rewrite it all), you wouldn't end up stackoverflowing; `equals()` would just be false, because they weren't meant to be equal.

What if a child is comparable to its parent ? If you're respecting LSP, the child shouldn't have a different `equals()` than his parent (ie: equals shouldn't be overriden), I guess. So the asymetric case shouldn't exists.

If a child is comparable to its parent, but has more parameters ? This is now your design, not respecting LSP, so it's up to you to see what meaning it does have in your context and act accordingly.

---

EDIT:@Adrian yes, "does symmmetry makes sense" was poor wording, I should have said "does the comparaison makes sense ?".

For your example, if you compare two child class with `getClass()` and they use super with also `getClass()` it will return true (the test will be redondant, because `this.getClass()` and `other.getClass()` will always have the same values, in the child and in the parent). But as I said, if you compare a child and a parent, it will be false (and I think it's normal if they have different parameters).

Why use final only on equals with instance of ? You said it, because of possible assymetry, whereas it's not possible to be assymetric with inheritance using `getClass()`, so it's no use making it final in this case.

As a side note, if you use `getClass()`, then multiple child of the same parent won't be comparable ( always return false ). If you use `instanceof`, they can, but if they do, no child should override `equals()` for risking of breaking symmetry. (I think you got this, but I was wondering when  choose `insteanceof` instead of `getClass()` if it's so problematic).

Comment: from what I understand, symmetry is always one important behavior for proper `equals()` (and also reflexive, transitive and consistent). So, "symmetry make sense" should never be a question.  For the question of "using super.equals()", I guess you have misunderstood: what I mean is, if we are overriding `equals()` and using `getClass()` for type checking, although child class can only check equality against child class, it still need to compare its "super" part.  So the code should look like:

Comment: `boolean equals(Object o) { .....; if (this.getClass() != that.getClass()) return false; return super(that) && Objects.equals(this.childField, that.childField); }` for which it is also falling into the problem of incapcable of making use of `super.equals` (as it will always return false in such case).  Anyway, a good point in the interpretation of LSP.  That bring me another confusion: If it is the case, why people only suggest to mark `equals()` final in case of using `instanceof` but not `getClass()`?  It should apply to either cases isn't it?

Comment: @Adrian added an edit (too long for comment). That's a pretty interesting question, never thought of it this much ! thank you for asking

Comment: Personally I only use `instanceof` but not `getClass()`, mostly because of same reason of Joshua Bloch's (http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch17.html).  It is especially important if we adopted any framework that will do proxying etc automatically for  you (e.g. when using AOP in Spring, when using Hibernate that may give you lazy-fetching proxy etc), using `getClass()` is going to be problematic

Comment: @Adrian Ah yes, this is pretty true, there are a lot of frameworks that "suppose" that equals shouldn't use `getClass()` but `instanceof`. But they also suppose it's symmetric, I guess. I don't really think there is a general solution to both problem, you just have to be carefull.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any shortcoming of using this approach?

It wouldn't work. The method to call is determined at compile time. Polymorphism only apply to reference before `.` not after it.

```
other.equals(this); // always calls equals(Object); as `other` is an Object.
```

Also

```
other.getClass().getMethod("equals", /* method with no args */).getDeclaringClass();
```

I assume you wanted other.getClass().getMethod("equals", Parent.class) but you would have to catch `NoSuchMethodException`

> I believe call of getClass().method("equals").getDeclaringClass() should be quite cheap?

Not in my option. It's quicker than reading something from disk, but you wouldn't want to do this very often.

Last but not least you should ensure that a.equals(b) ==> b.equals(a) and if a.equals(b) then a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() which is hard to do is `a` and `b` are different types.

Comment: I actually means `getMethod("equals", Object.class)`, which is supposed to be the method overridden.  I don't quite get the first point, `equals()` declared in `Object` is actually `equals(Object)` then what's the problem calling it?

Comment: for hashCode, once you override equals, you should override hashCode on the same time, which shouldn't bring any problem.

Comment: @AdrianShum You can call but it makes the check redundant.

Comment: Actually not.  Contract we have in `Object` is `equals(Object)`, not `equals(Parent)`.  The whole purpose of above stuff is to check if `Object::equals(Object)` method are overridden  (so that Parent cannot simply do its actual logic which will cause asymmetric behavior).  Please note that `equals(Parent)` is never part of the contract for `Object`

Comment: @AdrianShum if you keep the hashCode() consistent, you usually don't want to override it.

Comment: @AdrianShum if equals(Object) has been overridden, how will this method be called?

Comment: Hash code is never meant to be consistent. If your child override equals, hashCode should be overridden accordingly, which is one basic practice that everyone (should) do